# Is “speaking off” a popular idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

There was the following statement in Washington Post (July 29) [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/checkpoint/wp/2017/07/29/john-kelly-trumps-new-chief-of-staff-wont-suffer-idiots-and-fools/?utm_term=.8a72199f9cf4) that came under the title, “*John Kelly, Trump’s new chief of staff, ‘**won’t suffer idiots and fools***.’”

> “Officials there had grown tired of the four-star general **speaking off
>   message** - about the president’s plan to shut down the prison in
>   Guantanamo Bay, Cuba, about the perceived vulnerability of America’s
>   borders, about the threat posed to American interests by any number of
>   terrorist organizations. Their relationship had become so strained
>   that in the weeks before he retired, multiple administration officials
>   went to the media and accused Kelly and other military leaders of
>   endeavoring to undermine the Guantánamo closure plan.”

There are “speak of,” “speak off-the-cuff,” “speak out (up)” as idioms in the dictionary at hand, but I don’t find “speak off.”
What does “speak off message” mean? Does it mean to give an outright message? Is it popular use of “speak”?

Additionally, though my question might look naïve to you, what does the new Chief of Staff won’t “suffer idiots and fools” exactly mean?

Comment: "won't suffer fools and idiots" means he won't put up with them. It is usually "won't suffer fools gladly", which means have little patience with fools. See the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/04/opinion/brooks-suffering-fools-gladly.html)

Comment: @ab2. Thanks a lot. the NYT article you introduced helped me to comprehend the usage of "not + suffer" phrase. Honestly, my understanding of the verb, suffer was limited only to the usage in the context of 'suffer from head ache, injury, financial difficulty' and the like.

Comment: ***not suffer fools gladly***: to have very little patience with people who you think are stupid or have stupid ideas. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-suffer-fools-gladly

Comment: The idiom is [speak off-the-cuff](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/speak+off-the-cuff),  the hyphenation, in this case, isn't absolutely required but get it wrong and it is confusing.

Comment: Voting to close; you're parsing the phrase in a nonsensical way which wrecks the grammaticality of the surrounding sentence. It is *speaking (off message)* not *(speaking off) message*.  **Please use the English Language Learner's SE**.

Comment: The top-ranked result in Google search for `"off message"` currently points to this question!

Comment: "off message" is similar to many "off *something*" phrases: speaking "off topic", telling an "off color" joke, singing "off key", being thrown "off balance", ...

Answer (score 98):

It's not *speaking off*. It's speaking *off message*. The verb is not important. *Off message* (or *off-message*) means deviating from a prescribed message.  Staying *on message* means sticking to the prescribed message.

> Adjective: **off-message**  'óf'me-sij
>
> (politics) publicly stating or supporting a policy counter to the official party policy

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=off+message)

(*Off the cuff* is another idiom, with a different meaning. But there too, it's not the verb "speaking" that is important.)

Comment: Works like speaking off camera or off the record, or going off road with an SUV.  Some of these would benefit with judicious hyphenation. Indeed, the OED prefers *off-message*.

Comment: Good answer; could be much improved by explaining "off message".

Comment: @fectin: Do you think something needs to be added to "*deviating from a prescribed message*"

Comment: @tchrist: Does the OED really prefer "*off-message*" in "*speaking off-message*" or just when it is used as an adjective before a noun: "*an off-message tweet*"? To me, that would be odd. Does the OED prefer "*he spoke off-the-record*"?

Comment: Off message or off-message: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/off-message - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-message - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/off-message - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off+message - http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/off-message - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/off-message

Comment: @drew I think it would not be clear to someone unfamiliar with the term that "off message" is the part that means deviating from the prescribed message.

Comment: @Drew Idk about OED, but AP Style says to use a hyphen in adjectives but also when it would be less confusing to add a hyphen, which this would certainly benefit from.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: FWIW, I don't think it is less confusing to use a hyphen in *speak off message*. You still need to know what "*off-message*" means. I think the rule of adjective-**before**-noun is relevant here. (It's not just about being used as an adjective.) But of course compound words can evolve - e.g., *run time* -> *run-time* -> *runtime*. At any given time, we can look at which forms are used most. Personally, I would write *speak off message*, *be on time*, *is [up to date](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/180617/51214)*, etc., but others are of course free to hyphenate there.

Comment: @Drew perhaps you're more used to this language than I am. Maybe it wouldn't be needed in a political piece, but I maintain a general audience would benefit from a hyphen.

Comment: I vote for the hyphen.  The confusion is from trying to parse "(speaking off) message" vs. "speaking (off message)". The hyphen in "speaking off-message" makes clear it's the latter.  This question likely would not have been asked had the hyphen been present.

Comment: @MontyHarder: As I said, "*You still need to know what "off-message" means.*" The question posed would have been slightly different ("*What does it mean to speak off-message?*"), but the sentence would still have been unclear to someone ignorant of the meaning.

Answer (score 15):

The phrase *off-message* (sometimes hyphenated, sometimes not) is a surprisingly recent term, but one often used in political journalism.

OED provides a definition:

> Not in accordance with a planned or intended message; spec. departing from official party policy.

The first attested use is from **1992** in *The Washington Post*:

> Although it [sc. the Clinton transition team] harnessed masterfully the new prestige of the president-elect.., it has also endured a torrent of stories about such ‘off message’ matters as homosexuals in the military and the role of Hillary Clinton.

In the case of that example, "off message" means not in accordance with the message the Clinton transition team *wanted* to focus on.  It was not "on their messaging agenda."

Similarly, in the example given, Kelly's statements are not aligned with the messaging preferred by the communications operatives around him, meaning that his remarks were *off message*.

Comment: The "off-message" is similar to Scaramucci's expletive ridden "off-the-record" threat that he leaked to *The New Yorker*, saying he was going to fire anyone who was caught leaking to the press. Only the recently appointed "Mooch" forgot to tell the reporter that he was **speaking off the record**.   The irony of it all...

Comment: The recently appointed communication director. Opps. Sorry, the recently fired... yikes!

Answer (score 8):

In this sentence, "off" goes with "message", to mean that the person spoke in a way that differs from the official message.

Often, I've seen this disambiguated by way of hyphenation, as in *off-message*.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-message

As for suffering idiots and fools, it means that the speaker will not tolerate others' stupidity.

If you're curious, here's a wiki on a related phrase: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffer_fools_gladly

Answer (score 5):

**"Speaking off message" is a popular idiom....**

Answering the banner question:'Is “speaking off” a popular idiom?' first; the OED defines idiom as:

> A group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words
>
> A form of expression natural to a language, person, or group of people.
>   "he had a feeling for phrase and idiom"
>
> The dialect of a people or part of a country.

~ the important part of idiom is that it's about a use of language  that develops *within a community*. 
As **RaceYouAnytime** says "Speaking off *message*" is a popular idiom in  political journalism, and became common usage in this area in the early '90s. Since then (in my experience) it has become a well-used & commonly understood idiom in other contexts such as business and public service instutions - at least in American English and British English.

Its use presupposes (1) that there is a common stance that a *particular group* (e.g.. management,  party officials,  employees, teachers within a school) should be taking (2) when *reporting to another group* (eg. employees, the press, customers, parents, respectively) and often that (3) there is some coercive power relationship which discourages expressing opinions which deviate from the "party line" (a much older political idiom). Its usage seems to coincide with the rise in influence of political managers and 'spin doctors'*.

As such it would be an entirely odd & unidiomatic to use it referring to something said  within group of friends, where differences in opinion are *usually* not *managed*!

*see ['The Thick of It'(2000's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thick_of_It) with ['Yes Minister'(1980's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_Minister) for a good satirical comparison of the new era with old in British politics

---

**similar usage...**

To better understand "off message" (**oddgirlout** discusses this too) and thereby to answer your other questions, it might be useful to imagine a hyphen in the phrase: "Speaking off-message" (as opposed to "Speaking *on*-message"). The use in (British & American) English has become widespread in the past (25?) years:

"I going off-line for a few days"

"our discussion has gone a bit off-topic in the last 5 minutes"

"you're looking a little off-colour today" (feeling ill)

(the hyphens are not required but would be understood and accepted)

---

**suffer fools...**

The line ‘won’t suffer idiots and fools’ refers to ["suffer fools gladly"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffer_fools_gladly) though quite why Kelly thinks it clever to add the superfluous "idiots" is beyond me!

Answer (score -2):

"Off message" I take to mean "off topic". The word "fools" has multiple meanings  and "idiots" is also used currently to indicate a number of different states. Since one man's fool may be another man's wise man, the expression gives us very little specific information about the General's ideas. Maybe the writer was warning Trump to change his ways and had difficulty finding the right word for the President.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: You clearly haven't read the article cited, nor any of the answers posted.

Comment: The question was "What does it exactly mean?".One cannot tell until the General defines what he means by "fools and idiots". I suggest we don't know unless he defines those words for us. This is after all political verbiage. Perhaps he means people of a opposite political persuasion. He is Mr.Trump's third selection within 6 months; remembering that should be helpful.

Comment: "...gives us very little specific information about the General's ideas" I disagree, it actually describes the general's personality, whether you agree with the journalist or not is up to you. But I'll trust the American journalist of the Washington Post who has actually meant the general in person.