# When do you use hyphens with compound adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, compounds

I understand there are numerous questions related to this question but nothing truly clarifies my problem.

I have been trying to understand when I should use hyphens in compound adjectives and I seem to get slightly different examples when doing research on various sites. Given the answered question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180611/do-i-keep-myself-up-to-date-or-up-to-date-on-something) it is implied that you should only use hyphens in compound adjectives when used *before* a noun and not after it. Simple enough, that should be applied throughout. However, it doesn't seem to be the case in numerous instances.

According to the thesaurus' website about [compound adjectives](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/compound-adjectives/) it mentions the following:

> " Compound adjectives can be used anywhere that other adjectives can. So, they can either come directly before nouns/pronouns or can be used as predicate adjectives together with linking verbs. "

And gives these examples:

> - Reading this book is an **eye-opening** experience.
> - Even though the car was 10 years old, it still looked **brand-new**.

It outlines that *brand-new* should indeed be hyphenated. It is not before any noun and is the end of a sentence. Why? I have seen various instances of compound adjectives being hyphenated after a noun. Are these cases wrong?

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't hyphenate _brand new_ in the second example.

Comment: Any reasoning? Would you refer to the referenced question that you should only hyphenate compound adjectives if they're *before* a noun?

Comment: Yes. _He has a brand-new car. The car is brand new_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you!